# Open macOS app from Parallels

Tags: parallels-desktop

I want to open a macOS app from Windows (running on Parallels). For example, clicking into RetroArch.app/Contents/MacOS/RetroArch from Windows gives me the options to open the file with a macOS app. This is not what I want. This should open the app itself immediately, as it does on macOS.

Comment: In macOS it opens in macOS environment (Unix) but in windows it can not be directly executed as it is running in a Windows environment.

Comment: Have you tried [Parallels Support on Twitter](https://twitter.com/parallelscares?s=21)? They are quite responsive though not always helpful!

Comment: It can be done in wine with cmd which is what bothers me about it. I have tried their forums, but I've got no help. I actually have the feeling this is impossible to do on Parallels as of now.